# Finding the Index of an item in a combo box XAML/C#/WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

so I've done a lot of research and tried many people's solutions, and nothing seems to work and I can't figure out why. 
I'm trying to find the Index of an item in my ComboBox:

```
string Index = programType.Items.IndexOf("Lose Weight").ToString();
```

Index is always "-1" even though there is definitely an item that has Content/Tag of "Lose Weight":

```
<ComboBox x:Name="programType" Header="Desired goal:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="30,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" PlaceholderText="Desired Goal">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Lose Weight" Tag="Lose Weight" IsSelected="True" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Get Healthier" Tag="Get Healthier"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Get Stronger" Tag="Get Stronger"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Cardio Booster" Tag="Cardio Booster"/>
</ComboBox>
```

As far as I can tell it should be working? I must be doing something wrong, any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add items this way, `Items` property contains objects of type `ComboBoxItem`. Use the following code to get the list of strings:

```
int index = programType.Items
    .Cast<ComboBoxItem>()
    .Select(c => (string)c.Content)
    .ToList()
    .IndexOf("Lose Weight");
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks so much! I don't know why I couldn't find this answer anywhere else. Thanks again!